# How to combine two SOQL query into one

Tags: apex, soql, query

Instead of writing two separate query and execute two separate time, I'm thinking if I can combine into one.

Here is my first query:

```
SELECT Has_Attachment__c,Id,Name, profile__c FROM profile__c
WHERE profile__c = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

the second query:

```
SELECT Id,Name,ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE parentid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to clarify the relationships? What type of object is the `Profile__c` lookup to? Are you looking for `Attachment` records under the same parent? Is it a required lookup?

Comment: looking for Attachment records under the same parent

Comment: parent to child relationship is a master/detail

Comment: But what *type* of object does `Profile__c` refer to?

Comment: You need to provide the objects relationships or is not going to be easy to let you know how to build your query. You can also take a look to this page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm for extra information on how to build your SOQL and SOSL queries.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: Master-Detail(Profile__c), there is a typo in my question from this  `comp_profile__c` to `profile__c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that your `Profile__c` field is a reference to an object called `Parent__c`. The first step is to find the corresponding `ChildRelationship` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm)). `Execute Anonymous` to the rescue:

```
for (ChildRelationship relationship : SObjectType.Parent__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relationship.getChildSObject() == Comp_Profile__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relationship.getRelationshipName()); // you need this in SOQL
```

Cool, so now you now the API Name to use in your subquery. It should look like `Comp_Profiles__r` or something like that. You can run the same process for `Attachment` and find that the relationship name is `Attachments`. Now, you need to do a subquery on the `Parent__c` object.

```
SELECT Name,
    (SELECT Name FROM Attachments),
    (SELECT Name, Has_Attachment__c FROM Comp_Profiles__r)
FROM Parent__c WHERE Id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

One SOQL Query can Address only one Object. Unless if you want to access the Parent Data. That is Limitation on SOQL.
If there is relation between these 2 objects you can.
If you use SOSL you can address multiple objects.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. You can query parent and child data via `SOQL`, as long as there is a relationship.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The English in this post seems to be second language and not perfect but it seems Siva is indicating the ability to query through the parent/child relationship.  ` Unless if you want to access the Parent Data`

Comment: @DougB It has been updated. Check the edit history, the initial answer indicated it was not possible.